# why do angular docs advice not to use public and private scope variables

Tags: javascript, angularjs, api

I'm currently using `$$` & `$` variables from `location` service, I just stumbled upon this piece of documentation. It says not to use them but does not provide reason. Please enlighten me!
https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.15/docs/api

> Angular Prefixes $ and $$: To prevent accidental name collisions with
>   your code, Angular prefixes names of public objects with $ and names
>   of private objects with $$. Please do not use the $ or $$ prefix in
>   your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Angular's `$`/`$$`-prefixed built-ins is okay.

Angular is just asking you to not *create* your own scope variables, services and the like using those prefixes as they are reserved for Angular built-ins, as to avoid naming conflicts.

This recommended practice is mainly to future-proof your code. Let's say, if you create a `$foo` service today and a future version of Angular adds a `$foo` built-in, there would be a naming conflict.

Following this recommendation, you just don't prefix your code with `$`/`$$` and it will not conflict with possible future Angular built-in additions that will be prefixed with `$`/`$$`.

As a byproduct, it also eases reading the code, as you can more easily distinguish between built-in components and custom ones.

Comment: Added some more in-depth explanation. `=]`